# How to refer to an image in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm very new to this all and trying to implement a carousel from bootstrap. I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 4.
I have saved an image:
app/assets/images/ball.gif
I have the following code:

```
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="<%= image_tag "ball.gif" %>" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Text</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

However, it doesn't show the image. How should I refer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
  <img src="<%= image_tag "ball.gif" %>" alt="First slide">
```

try

```
  <%= image_tag "ball.gif", alt: "First slide">
```

or

```
  <img src="<%= asset_path "ball.gif" %>" alt="First slide">
```

Comment: Thanks,   <img src="<%= asset_path "ball.gif" %>" alt="First slide"> worked!